# Number of database connections in Grafana

Tags: grafana

In Grafana it's possible to use an external database for keeping the configuration. I use MySQL and the question is if there is any option to configure the maximum number of internal database connections in Grafana?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to set `max_conn` as the issue is closed: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/7427